# Lawyer Base WordPress GoodLayer theme sidebar issues

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created page "Events" and set page layout as "both sidebar". And then
I have updated my page layout from "**both sidebar**" to "**without sidebar**", and then I revert back to both sidebar but now it is not working it stick in one that is without sidebar.

After all this action page layout checked on one options that is "Without sidebar" and disabled both sidebar. I am using **LawyerBase** theme in WordPress (**GoodLayer**).

Comment: share your website URL

Comment: @DevKiran: we would rather have self-contained questions here, so asking for a URL would encourage OPs generally not to show the problem in the question. I guess we'd need to see some HTML and CSS here, and perhaps a JSFiddle.

Comment: This can be closed as not having an [mcve].